# Python - variable as list index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm wondering if this is possible in python.
I'm accessing a list in this way:

```
print list[0]['name']
```

This is fine. Is there a way to use a variable? 
I mean:

```
a="[0]['name']"
print list[a]
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Some details:

I have a situation where I have something like this:

```
a = [{"name":"someone", "age":23}]
print a[0]['name']
```

But since I need to pass "[0]['name']" as parameter, I'd like to understand if this is possible.
Thanks,

cips

Comment: You need to explain why you need this. Otherwise it can only be accomplished with `eval` or `exec`

Comment: Do you want to use this particular string to index your list, or could the variable have a different value? For example `a = [0, 'name']`?

Comment: Please see my edit below.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In general it is [dangerous to use `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) but you essentially need to convert your string to perform your indexing.

So first you can get your list as a `str` using `repr`

```
>>> l = [{'name': 'bob'}]
>>> repr(l)
"[{'name': 'bob'}]"
```

then if you concatenate that with your index operation

```
>>> a = "[0]['name']"
>>> repr(l) + a
"[{'name': 'bob'}][0]['name']"
```

then `eval` the whole thing, it should do the trick

```
>>> eval(repr(l) + a)
'bob'
```

Comment: Please, no. Avoiding `eval` is almost _trivial_ in this case; you can easily parse the string `"[0]['name']"` into a list like `[0, 'name']` and then use those values to index `a`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple matter of extracting the indices/keys from the string `"[0]['name']"` and then using those keys to index the list/dict structure.

```
data = [{"name":"someone", "age":23}]
keys = "[0]['name']"

# split the string into a list of indices/keys
keys = keys[1:-1].split('][')
# keys = ['0', "'name'"]

# the keys are all strings, so we have to convert
# each individual key to the correct type
import ast
keys = [ast.literal_eval(key) for key in keys]
# keys = [0, 'name']

# now use the list of indices/keys we generated to get the value
value = data
for key in keys:
    value = value[key]

print(value) # output: someone
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope not to be out of context, but maybe you can use a function like this if you can
convert `s = "[0]['name']"` to `s = (0, 'name')`:

```
def search_index(obj, itero):
    try:
        return search_index(obj[next(itero)], itero)
    except StopIteration:
        return obj

a = [{"name":"someone", "age":23}]
s = (0, 'name')

result = search_index(a, iter(s))
# >>> result = 'someone'
```

If you want to convert `"[0]['name']"` to `(0, 'name')` you can try this:

```
import re
reg = re.findall(r'\[(\d*?)\]|\[\'(\w*?)\'\]', "[0]['name']")
s = [int(index[0]) if not index[1] else index[1] for index in reg]
# [0, 'name']
```

It will convert the indexes to the right type, to work with either list or dicts.

Answer (score -3):

you can use the function eval('a[0][name]'), it will evaluate the string inside as a python code.

here is the reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [answer] to write better answers in the future.

Comment: Please don't advocate the use of `eval` or `exec`. It's near-trivial to solve the OP's problem _without_ `eval`. `eval` opens a massive security hole in your code for no reason.

Answer (score -4):

You can use exec command

```
exec("print(list{})".format(a))
```

I hope it works

Comment: Please don't advocate the use of `eval` or `exec`. It's near-trivial to solve the OP's problem _without_ `exec`. `exec` opens a massive security hole in your code for no reason.